# how can i set different menus on different pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to setup diffrent menu for diffrent page like.

In Home Page I need to main menu link like this

```
<a href='#home'>Home</a>
<a href='http://example.com/product'>Product</a>
<a href='#services'>Services</a>
<a href='#conact'>Contact Us</a>
```

In product Page

```
<a href='http://example.com/#home'>Home</a>
<a href='http://example.com/product'>Product</a>
<a href='http://example.com/#services'>Services</a>
<a href='http://example.com/#conact'>Contact Us</a>
```

I am using one page theme so please help me for this logic development.
Thanks

Comment: you can make two menus and add that in header file on basis of condition like is_front_page

Comment: Please share your PHP code for that section of your site. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "one page theme"...Your link structure points to two pages.

Comment: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/#portfolio
Like this my templates of word press. so i need to home page menu look like this but i have one more page which is product page. so in product page this menu link doesn't work for redirect on home page

Comment: @Yatendra it is unlikely that every page except for the front page will be a product page as per the WP-Theme hierarchy. It would be more efficient to use the `is_page_template()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to answer this question without seeing more code, but in an abstract sense this can be achieved quite easily. As [Yatendra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846524/yatendra) pointed out, you need to register two menus as so in your functions.php file:

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'home-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'product-menu' => __( 'Product Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Then, you will want to embed something similar into your header.php where you navigation should like usding the `is_page_template()` and `wp_nav_menu()` functions.

```
<?php 

    if (is_page_template( 'products.php' )) // change this to the name of the file
    {
         // load the product-menu
         wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'product-menu' ) );         
    }
    else
    {
         // load the header-menu
         wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); 
    }
?>
```

However, for a one-page theme, something like a parallax theme you are better not putting in a conditional and wrapping them in `<div>` tags and show and hiding them with jQuery. However, we would really need to see more code.

Codex References:

1. [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)
2. [Registering a Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)